# Calling c# then js on same element

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using the following `c#` to change content from the server side:

```
this.StatusPreview.InnerHtml = "server side";
this.StatusPreview.Update();
```

I am using the following `js` to change content on the client side:

```
document.getElementById('StatusPreview').innerHTML = "client side";
```

If I execute the `js` first, there is no problem. However, If I execute the `c#` first, then the `js`, I get a,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

on the `js` line.

This is the element being affected:

```
<td id="StatusPreview" runat="server"> </td>
```

When I execute the `c#`, it changed the `td` to

```
<span id="el_StatusPreview_container">asd</span>
```

Is there a way that would allow me to update `c#` first, without turning my element `null`?

Thank you!

Comment: in the server side code, add:  this.StatusPreview.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;  This will tell asp.net to leave the ID as is, and not rename it.  I generally use this for controls on the page, and I haven't used it in the server side, but it should work.

Comment: @CMKanode ` this.StatusPreview.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static` did not prevent the element from being renamed

Comment: I missed the part of it creating a new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to update via server side and client side, you should change your methodology.

Leave the td tag as a plain tag, and add a label as a child:

```
<asp:Label ID="StatusPreview" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

If JavaScript updates it first, it will find the element.  If the server side updates it, then with the ClientIDMode set to static, it will not change the ID and since it is a web control already, it will not  create a new element, hence the JavaScript can still find it.

Comment: Excellent idea! I used `this.StatusPreview.Text` in `c#` instead of `InnerHtml` and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `td` is being turned into a `span` but the javascript cannot find it because of the ASP.NET naming convention, where by default it will add the `ID` of its parent `INamingContainer` to the `ClientID` of the element. You can get around this by setting the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) of the control to `Static`, so that it will be set to the same as the `ID`:

```
<td id="StatusPreview" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"> </td>
```

Comment: I set the `ClientIdMode` to `static` but this did not change anything, I still get the same error. The ID still gets renamed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.getElementById('<%= StatusPreview.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "client side";
```

This will change id of **StatusPreview** in accordance to it's id at client side.

Comment: This gives me the same `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null ` exception when trying to call the `js` for the first time.